# Which Kotlin Multiplatform Plugin should I install to have Compose Multiplatform on Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I'm exploring Compose Multiplatform, which creates Compose projects for Android, iOS, Web and/or Desktop.

I wanted to install the Plugin, and I saw 3 of them (as shown in picture below)

1. Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile
2. Compose Multiplatform IDE Support
3. Full-Multiplatform-Compose

Should I install all 3 of them (i.e. 1, 2 then 3), or can I just install 3 only (Or any combination of them)?

[image]

Comment: The 1st one for sure. The 2nd is Compose FOR desktop (but the plugin says: "The main feature at the moment is IDE preview of composable functions marked by @Preview annotation." So not much there . The 3rd one is made by someone and is theoretically just a "template" to get you started (could be useful to save you all the initial boilerplate and dependency hell Google is creating with all this together with JetBrains, *but* could be outdated...)

Answer (score 1):

Please just read the first lines of the plugin description.

1. The Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile plugin helps you develop applications that work on both Android and iOS.
   Made by JetBrains
2. IDE support for developing Compose for Desktop.
   Made by JetBrains
3. 1K downloads made by jakepurple13

Of course, you should use the first one.